# How to find out the matching file names for the extension .pdf along with the URL and get the data in google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Let suppose , there are 100 file in a folder "A" in google drive. Each file has got the name which of is 5 character. Eg 12345 and in the folder there are couple of file with the matching name i.e 12345-A and 12345- B. I want the script which should ignore the - A and - B in the matching file name and should return the file URl in the sheet at range A1. Can any one help on this.  Additionally, the idea is to get the matching file to combine in one pdf file and save in the google drive with the URL.

Comment: Is there any attempt you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
// Example files
let files = ["test1-A","test2-B", "test1-B", "test2-A"];

// Where to store files with the same name you described
let similar = {};

// Sorting the files
for(let file of files) {
  let name = file.match(/^[a-z0-9]+/i)[0]; // Removes the trailing '-A' and '-B'
  if(typeof similar[name] === "undefined") similar[name] = []
  similar[name].push(file)
}
console.log(similar)
```

This should produce the following result:

```js
{
  test1: ["test1-A", "test1-B"],
  test2: ["test2-B", "test1-A"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You will have to use the `Drive` service from Apps Script.**

So for example, in order to get the files that contain "12345" in their title, you will have to create a query and then based on the id of the folder where you want to search, you use the `searchFiles` method.

```
var query = 'title contains "12345"';
var searchResults = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER_ID').searchFiles(query);
```

Afterwards, depending on your task, you can access these files by using the `hasNext` method

```
while (searchResults.hasNext()) {
    var file = searchResults.next();
    // do other tasks
}
```

As for accessing a spreadsheet, you will have to use the `Spreadsheet` service and the following methods can help you achieve your task:

- `getRange` - depending on the parameters you choose for this method, this will return the range from the spredsheet;
- `setValue` - this will set the value for the range;

#### Reference

- [Apps Script DriveApp Class - searchFiles(params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column);
- [Apps Script Range Class - setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).